# Tomcat Session data getting mixed

Tags: session, iis-7, struts2, tomcat6

We are running Tomcat behind IIS7 on Windows 2008 RC2 Server.

We are storing some variables for users in session, sometimes session data for one user is picked up for another user who are not using the same browser. How can this be possible.

Regards,
Abhijit

Comment: Most likely it isn't possible, and you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Just edited my question, We are running Tomcat behind IIS7 on Windows 2008 RC2 Server.

Comment: Are the session IDs different?

Comment: There are not enough details here to help. Do some testing and compare the session IDs that are issued and reported back to the server for each user.